# Why Serialize methods needs instance to use?

Tags: c#, serialization

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace FileApp
{
    [Serializable]
    class NameCard
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Phone;
        public int Age;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream ws = new FileStream("a.dat", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

            NameCard nc = new NameCard();
            nc.Name = "dd";
            nc.Phone = "111";
            nc.Age = 33;

            serializer.Serialize(ws, nc);
            ws.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

why Ihave to make instance to Serialize(ws, nc);
I think this method can be static because it doenst need any state. Serialized nc field saved in ws Stream, right? Then why BinaryFormatter type serializer needs

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please consider using some other serialization method. BinaryFormatter have issues with security, performance, size and backwards compatibility. I would recommend some standard serialization format like Json or Protobuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formatter doesn't need any state and could be static, that's true.

But there is a bigger context. The class implements the `IFormatter` interface as [several classes too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter).

This means in your code you can say you'd like to get an `IFormatter` to serialize or deserialize your data to stick to the SOC. Also if your program uses a DI container you can replace the used formatter, depending of the usage.

So in general static methods of classes can make problems, if you like to use the same class (containing this method) in different contexts. The most common used static instance method that can make problems in unit tests for example is `DateTime.Now`. If you implement something depending on time (e.g. test if timeout is reached after 20 secs) your test has to run 20 secs in real-time for doing nothing. If you use something like a `IScheduler` you can use in your productive code a simple class that returns when requested `DateTime.Now`, but in your tests you code use a mocked instance that can *time-travel* to make these tests run faster.